# definition of "character"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, vocabulary

I wonder if "character" could be explained as "something that exists separately from other things and has a clear identity of its own" in a strict sense. In my opinion, character is not "something" but "some trait that makes something exist separately from other things". What are your opinions?

Comment: I thought we did this one before?

Comment: No need to repeat your own question. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570279/what-is-character